# Image Geometrical remapping on OpenGL ES

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, opengl-es

I have an algorithem that runs on PC and uses OpenCV remap. It is slow and I need to run it on an embedded system (for example a device such as this: http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php

It has OpenGL 3.0 and I am wondering if it is possible to write code in OpenGL shader to do the remapping (OpenCV remapping).

I have another device that has OpenGL 2.0, Can that device do shader programming?

where can I learn about shader programming in OpenGL?

I am using Linux.

## Edit 1

The code runs on a PC and it takes around 1min, On am embedded system it takes around 2 hours!

I need to run it on an embedded system and for that reason I think to use OpenGL or OpenCL (the board has OpenCL 1.1 driver).

What is the best option for this? Can I use OpenGl 2 or OpenGL3?

Answer (score 0):

A PC with a good graphic card (compatible with OpenCV) is much faster than a little embedded PC like Odroid or Banana Pi. I mean that computational_power/price or computational_power/energy is lower on these platforms.

If your algorithm is slow:

- Are you sure your graphic driver is correctly configured to support OpenCV?
- Try to improve your algorithm. On a current PC, is easy to get 1TFLOP with OpenCL, so if your program really require more, you should think about computer clouds and such. Check that you configured the appropriate buffers type, etc.

OpenGL 3 allow general shaders, but OpenGL 2 is very different and it must be much harder or impossible to make your algorithm compatible.

To learn OpenGL/GLSL, be very care because most page learn bad/old code. 
I recommend you a good book, like: [http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Shading-Language-Cookbook-Edition/dp/1782167021/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782167021)

EDIT 1

OpenGL 3+, or OpenGL ES 3+ have general purpose shaders and may be used for fast computing. So yes, you will get performance increased. But graphic cards on these platform are very small/slow (usually less than 10 cores). Do not expect to get the same 1min-result on this ODROID than on your PC with 500-2000 GPU cores.

OpenGL 2 has fixed pipeline and it is hard to use it for parallel computing.

If you really require to use an embedded platform, maybe you may use a cloud of them?

Comment: Thanks. I may make it a bit confusing. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Thanks. On PC I am not using OpenGL, but just processing on CPU. I want to use OprnGL or OpenCL on these devices to do fast processing and reducing the processing to something comparable.

Comment: 120min to 1min is a lot of difference! Have you checked where this time is lost? Memory access (cache or allocation), S.O., etc.

Comment: It is mainly in remap function of opencv